# Power supply filtering of ICs

Tags: capacitor, integrated-circuit, filter, inductor

My question is - why in 99% of designs we dont need to provide RC filter to the power supply of IC, just individual capacitor is required? I know, that paths does have some resistance, but still, the lowest resistance in RC filter, the bigger bandwidth it provides, what is not required. Why do we need only capacitor instead of RC filter - do we bases on internal DC power supply resistance?

My second question is - why sometimes (like DDR3 VDD filtering) we need LC filter instead of just capacitor with bigger capacitance? Is it related to decreasing the price of design?

Comment: RC filters are not used everywhere, I have seen RC filters used when there is certain attenuation required for certain frequency ranges like for Clock buffers. I don't know usage of LC filter for DDR3 VDD filtering

Comment: RC filters have significant DC insertion loss due to Ohm's law; so load/line regulation is worse the greater the R. With high speed switching (including fast rise/fall time signals), the spiky demand in load current becomes a reduction in supply voltage. So the power supply and ground return systems have to be designed to minimize resistance, to prevent supply dropout and ground bounce.

Answer (score 6):

A filter capacitor close to a chip pin can serve many purposes; some of those would benefit from a filtering resistor - or even better, inductor, while some other would not benefit.

Imagine a digital IC, such a microcontroller. Its purpose is to charge and discharge a lot of CMOS gates several millions times per second, and in order to do that it needs a lot of charge close by. If the power supply is "far away", the additional inductance of the wires/traces will make the local input voltage sag quite a bit. Here, you are using a capacitor to lower the local VDD impedance to ground - you do not care about noise, adding a resistor would increase the impedance (and cost money) so you do not do it.

Consider instead the REF input of an ADC. The current demand of such pins is usually in the µA range, therefore adding a series resistor is not a problem, and in doing so you are reducing the BW of the wideband noise that you provide to the IC.

These are just two basic examples, but I hope they show that when it comes to decouplers, there are many factors that come in to the game:

- What DC current do I expect? Can I afford a series R?
- What impedance to ground do I need at the decoupled pin?
- Am I trying to reduce the noise that goes in to the chip?
- ...

Depending on the above, and other factors, you can devise a strategy and implement it, but there is no "one size fits all" solution.

Comment: Instead of RC filter we can use transistor capacitance multiplier, why not to use that? https://audioxpress.com/article/the-capacitance-multiplier

Answer (score 4):

> *why in 99% of designs we dont need to provide RC filter to the power
> supply of IC, just individual capacitor is required?*

Well, it's not resistance in the copper feeds to the chip that are either relevant or important here. The important aspect of power supply connections to a chip is the effective series inductance. This is the parasitic inductance of the feed wires/tracks/copper.

That inductance limits the peak current draw of the chip when the chip is taking a pulsing current. The capacitor applied to the chip legs acts as a reservoir of energy so that the chip can locally obtain its needed peak currents.

Then you find that keeping those pulsing currents local has a benefit - it produces the smallest loop area and minimizes emitted radiation.

> *My second question is - why sometimes (like DDR3 VDD filtering) we
> need LC filter instead of just capacitor with bigger capacitance?*

Can you see how this 2nd question is now related to the parasitic inductance problem I described above. An added inductor prevents (to a much greater degree) any pulse currents affecting other parts of the circuit i.e. the inductor acts like an EMC isolator.

We design power feeds to chips on a PCB to be low in resistance so that static DC currents are not producing a constant volt drop and causing the circuit chips to be fed with an under-voltage.

Comment: Instead of RC filter we can use transistor capacitance multiplier, why not to use that? https://audioxpress.com/article/the-capacitance-multiplier

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd you would never do that for the power supply feed to each IC in a design. That is what this question is about.

Comment: Because of price? or circuit getting more complex?

Comment: Because it misses the point - high frequency decoupling of power supply series inductance requires low-value high-quality capacitors and not (never in fact) a capacitance multiplier. It just won't do what it's meant to do. If you are still unsure, please formally raise a new question.